# Rails nested smart_listing 'persisted' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with creating new item in smart_listing. My routes

```
resources :cars do
  resources :persons
end
```

And I added deleting/editing which work perfectly. But when I need create new person, I have this error:

```
undefined method `persisted?' for "/cars/1/persons/201":String
```

My Person controller

```
def create
  @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
  @person = @car.persons.create(person_params)
end
```

My create.js.erb

```
<%= smart_listing_item :persons, :create, car_person_path(@car, @person),
                       @person.valid? ? "person/person" : "person/form" %>
```

My stack higlight first line in create.js.erb with error above. How fix this ? :)

Comment: I don't know anything about `smart_listing`, but it seems to be trying to do something with that third argument to your `smart_listing_item`. Are you sure `smart_listing_item` takes a route as its third argument? Seems like it may be expecting an ActiveRecord object.

Comment: pass @person as third Argument to smart_listing_item in view

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling the method with the wrong parameters. According to the gem's [example](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing/blob/master/README.md#list-item-management-and-in-place-editing), third parameter should be an instance of you model:

```
<%= smart_listing_item :users, :new, @new_user, "users/form" %>
```

In you example, the third parameter is the `url` and not a instance of the model.

Comment: But when I add @person as third parameter, I have error when creating: `missing required keys: [:car_id]`

Comment: Which means user model should have a `car_id`